# How to add an existing library to Ubuntu snap core?

Tags: snap, ld

I'm a total newbie to [***snap***](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage).  Apologies if this question is trivial.

I'm experiencing unintended side effects when trying to use `snap` on a slightly customized Ubuntu system.

**My slight customization is:**

To replace the standard malloc with `libjemalloc` (better performance, works well, never encountered an issue), I have this in `/etc/ld.so.preload`

```
#--override the system malloc--#
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so
```

Understandably, `libjemalloc.so` is not included in the ubuntu snap core package.

**Which leads to the following side effects when trying to use `snap`:**

```
$ snap list
Name         Version  Rev  Developer  Notes
core         16.04.1  888  canonical  -
hello        2.10     20   canonical  -

$ /snap/bin/hello
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Hello, world!
```

**Questions:**

- Why does the ERROR repeat 3 times?  Is this a bug?
- Why does the `snap` system try to inherit this preload. Shouldn't containers be self contained and be isolated from the caller user-land environment?  Is this a bug?
- What's the easiest way to add `libjemalloc.so` to the core snap, preferably as an overlay that doesn't include all of the core?